# Display page elements based on multiple checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, dom

I am just getting into JS/jquery and attempting to display page elements based on multiple checkbox selections.
I want all elements to start displayed with all checkboxes unchecked and then as I make one or more checkbox selections, have only elements of the selected div class display (all others will hide unless all checkboxes are unchecked).

The trap I am in is that it is working in reverse, so when I start with all showing and checkboxes unchecked, I check one (or more) and the elements with the selected values disappear.

The more complicated trap is that some of the elements may have multiple class values, as per the summer & winter one. This will then hide if I deselect/select one of the checkboxes.

Your help is tremendously appreciated with this dilemma.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="mySeason"]').click(function () {
      var x = $(this).attr("value");
      $("." + x).toggle();
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="summer" /> Summer</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="autumn" /> Autumn</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="winter" /> Winter</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="spring" /> Spring</label>
</div>

<div class="summer">Summer</div>
<div class="autumn">Autumn</div>
<div class="summer winter">Summer &amp; Winter</div>
<div class="winter">Winter</div>
<div class="spring">Spring</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this the most simple way you could add a single common class to all the target seasons. Then you can use `map()` to build a selector to target them, hiding any elements which do not have any of the checked classes.

Also note that it's good practice to use `change()` instead of `click()` when dealing with checkbox or radio buttons. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $seasons = $('.season');
  let $checkboxes = $('input[name="mySeason"]').on('change', function() {
    $seasons.show();
    
    let selector = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => '.' + el.value).get().join(',');
    if (selector.length != 0)
      $seasons.filter(`:not("${selector}")`).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="summer" /> Summer</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="autumn" /> Autumn</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="winter" /> Winter</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="spring" /> Spring</label>
</div>
<div class="season summer">Summer</div>
<div class="season autumn">Autumn</div>
<div class="season summer winter">Summer &amp; Winter</div>
<div class="season winter">Winter</div>
<div class="season spring">Spring</div>
```

*- Update -*

Regarding your comment converting the 'Or' logic above to 'And', all you need to do is remove the `,` from the selector - note the amendment to `join()` in this version.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $seasons = $('.season');
  let $checkboxes = $('input[name="mySeason"]').on('change', function() {
    $seasons.show();
    
    let selector = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => '.' + el.value).get().join('');
    if (selector.length != 0)
      $seasons.filter(`:not("${selector}")`).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="summer" /> Summer</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="autumn" /> Autumn</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="winter" /> Winter</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="mySeason" value="spring" /> Spring</label>
</div>
<div class="season summer">Summer</div>
<div class="season autumn">Autumn</div>
<div class="season summer winter">Summer &amp; Winter</div>
<div class="season winter">Winter</div>
<div class="season spring">Spring</div>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks, Rory. This is a great way for me to learn, by walking through and trying to understand what is happening in your code.

Would it be much more complicated to extend so that it displays/hides according to all the checkbox criteria being met. In my own head I would need an array of all checked boxes when one is checked or unchecked and then select all divs that contain all elements in the array.
 To demonstrate what I mean, I added to the html here: https://jsfiddle.net/MrSixty7/2svzdyxf/1/
If I select summer and 31, I would only want "Summer August 31" to display

Comment: No problem glad to help. To turn the logic in to an 'and' operation all you need to do is remove the `,` that's generated between the selectors. E.g. `.summer,.winter` would select elements which have either class whereas `.summer.winter` selects only elements with both classes. I've updated the question with a working example for you.

Comment: Thanks again, Rory. Now I will try and figure out how to mix up both and/or by creating checkbox groups (by name) for each 'category' (mySeason, myMonth, myDays).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label>input type="checkbox" onchange="toggl('summer')"> Summer</label>
<label>input type="checkbox" onchange="toggl('autumn')"> Autumn</label>
<label>input type="checkbox" onchange="toggl('winter')"> Winter</label>
<label>input type="checkbox" onchange="toggl('spring')"> Spring</label>
<div id="summer">Summer</div>
<div id="autumn">Autumn</div>
<div id="winter">Winter</div>
<div id="spring">Spring</div>
<script>
function toggl(id) {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el.style.visibility == "hidden") el.style.visibility = "visible";
    else el.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

Use the ID property, so you don't need to mess with class indexes.

Comment: Appreciate the reponse but that seems to work in the same way; it hides the <div> when I check the relevant checkbox. It also does not handle any div's that have a multiple ID e.g.
 
    <div id="winter summer">Winter Summer</div>[